# HTTP Request Handler Connection Reset Error

Tags: java, multithreading, http, libgdx

I am writing up a simple HTTP request handler, but kept randomly encountering **Connection Reset** errors while transmitting files over to the client browser.

Since my program is rather large, I will simplify the codes a bit below:

```
public class HTTPRequestHandler implements Runnable {
    private Queue<HTTPRequest> requests;
    private volatile boolean flag;
    ...
    public void run() {
        flag = true;
        while (flag) {
            HTTPRequest request = null;
            synchronized(this) {
                if (requests.size > 0) {
                     request = requests.removeFirst();
                }
            }

            if (request != null) {
                handleRequest(request);
            }
        }
    }
    ...
    private void handleRequest(HTTPRequest request) {
        ...
        try {
            // Send HTTP Header
            request.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(message.getHeader().getBytes());

            // Send HTTP Message Body
            Object messageBody = message.getMessageBody();
            if (messageBody != null && messageBody.getClass() == File.class) {
                Files.copy(((File)messageBody).toPath(), request.getSocket().getOutputStream());
                request.getSocket().getOutputStream().flush();
            } else if (messageBody != null) {
                ...
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ...
    }
```

I was able to get this part to work most of the times (not always) on various browsers on a local machine, but it never works at all on a remote machine. It is happening randomly for mainly large file and sometimes for small files as well.

As for HTTP header, I currently have the program close the connection after each complete response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem with this design after doing some packet sniffing. The server is sending too much packets too fast before the client can acknowledge receiving them. As a result, the server sends a TCP reset to the client. When the client attempts to reestablish connection, the server refuses to accept the connection since it already exit the statement for sending the file and has closed the socket connection. The client moves on with other files and will attempt to request the incomplete file again. The server will then send the file again, but the client will fail to acknowledge in time as usual. At this point, the client just gives up with that file.

Since my design can handle only one request at a time and isn't able to pick up from where it might leave off, modify my code to divide the file in chunks and send one chunk at a time after sleeping for one millisecond.

```
if (messageBody != null && messageBody.getClass() == File.class) {
    InputStream fileStream = new FileInputStream((File)messageBody);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1460]; // Maximum TCP packet size
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = fileStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        request.getSocket().getOutputStream().write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    fileStream.close();
}
```